# tabbar scroll picture button grayed out when only one tab is active

Tags: tabbar, buttons

I replaced the image for tabbar scroll. Original:

[image]

Replaced them with the following lines in the init file:

```
  ;; Load a new tabbar arrow image
  (setq tabbar-scroll-left-button-enabled-image-one '((:type png :file "~/tabbar-scroll-left.png" :ascent center)))
  (setq tabbar-scroll-left-button
        (cons (cons " <" tabbar-scroll-left-button-enabled-image-one)
              (cons " =" nil)))
  (setq tabbar-scroll-right-button-enabled-image-one '((:type png :file "~/tabbar-scroll-right.png" :ascent center)))
  (setq tabbar-scroll-right-button
        (cons (cons " >" tabbar-scroll-right-button-enabled-image-one)
              (cons " =" nil)))
```

I replaced them with a colored picture, but they are only colored when there are multiple tabs.

With only one tab (both scroll pictures are greyed out):

[image]

With two tabs (Right scroll icon is showing as colored, which is desired when they are always colored):

[image]

The desired scenario is to have the two scroll image always colored. I investigated tabbar.el but did not have a clue where it defines behavior of graying out a colored picture. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `tabbar-line-buttons` chooses between the `car` and `cdr` of the three variables for which there is an on/off depending upon different circumstances:  `tabbar-home-button-value`; `tabbar-scroll-left-button-value`; and `tabbar-scroll-right-button-value`.  For the arrows, the starting tab is compared to the number of tabs.

---

The function `tabbar-line-button` sets the above-mentioned three variables.  I put the three variables in comments near this function, because I would never think to search for `"tabbar-%s-button-value"`.